# Java Script Add Event Listener

Tags: javascript, event-handling

Im trying to attach an event listener but instead of an event such as 'click' I want it to be when a variable meets a certain criteria. For example:

```html
let x = 1;
let y = 2;

const myObject = document.getElementById('myObject')

myObject.addEventListener('x==3 && y == 4', function() {
}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible or not without using the if statement within the function but maybe you guys had a solution or a way to work around that ? Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Is the `myObject` a `input`?

Comment: So you want to trigger a function as soon as the variables change and meet a specific condition? That’s not event listeners, that would be observable objects. Don’t use variables, use an object with `x` and `y` as properties and wrap them in a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), then you can change those properties whenever you want and each time they are changed, you can run a function. If you just want to check the condition upon clicking, then just use the `click` event with the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your `myObject` element knows what the values of x and y are, but you can add event listeners to the id of some element that causes the change to x or y, and run a function that checks their values. If you want to trigger an entirely different event when x and y hit the desired values, just call a function inside the if statement that checks for the values you want. This example resets the values if either x or y reach 10. Hope this is helpful in some way!

```js
const xElem = document.getElementById('x');
const yElem = document.getElementById('y');
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

xElem.addEventListener('click', changeFunction);
yElem.addEventListener('click', changeFunction);

function changeX(){
  x++;
  xElem.innerHTML = `x = ${x}`;
}

function changeY(){
  y++;
  yElem.innerHTML = `y = ${y}`;
}

function changeFunction() {
  if(x == 3 && y == 4){
    alert('there you have it!');
  }
  if(x == 10 || y == 10){
    doThisOtherThing()
  }
}

function doThisOtherThing() {
  alert('reset');
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  xElem.innerHTML = 'change x';
  yElem.innerHTML = 'change y';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="x" onClick="changeX()">change x</button>
  <button id="y" onClick="changeY()">change y</button>
</div>
```